# How to add random words up to n times in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I want a numpy array of size n, with words from the list `words = ["high","low","neutral"]` filled up to size n randomly.

I tried `x = [random.sample(words,1) for i in range(1,101)]`.

This gave the output like this:  `[['low'],['high']...]`

**I want the output as:**  `['high','low','low',....]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```py
x = random.choices(words, k=100)
```

The docs for `random.choices()` state:

> **Return a `k` sized list of elements chosen from the population with replacement.** If the population is empty, raises `IndexError`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are doing it right, but random.sample returns the list of random selections so in your case you can do either replace the

```
x = [random.sample(words,1) for i in range(1,101)]
```

**with**

```
x = [random.sample(words,1)[0] for i in range(1,101)]
```

> Output ['high', 'low', 'low', . . .]

**Or also you can use list comprehension to tackle this, e.g.**

```
x = [x[0] for x in x]
```

> Output ['high', 'low', 'low', . . .]

Or you can simply make it super simple one liner by using random.choices

```
x = random.choices(words, k=100)
```

> Output ['high', 'low', 'low', . . .]

Comment: A list comprehension will not create a numpy array

Comment: Thanks! This did fix my issue. I saw resources on the internet suggesting ```random.choice()``` but I didn't know about the parameters. Thanks again.

Comment: for the other users in this community accept the answer